# mod_rewrite: remove trailing slash (only one!)

Tags: apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, redirect, url-rewriting

I use mod_rewrite/.htaccess for pretty URLs.

I'm using this condition/rule to eliminate trailing slashes (or rather: rewrite to the non-trailing-slash-URL, by a 301 redirect; I'm doing this to avoid duplicate content and because I like URLs with no trailing slashes better):

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^\.localhost$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.+)/$ http://%{HTTP_HOST}/$1 [R=301,L]
```

Working well so far. Only drawback:
it also forwards *"multiple-trailing-slash"-URLs* to *non-trailing-slash-URLs*.

Example:
`http://example.tld/foo/bar//////` forwards to `http://example.tld/foo/bar`
while I only want `http://example.tld/foo/bar/` to forward to `http://example.tld/foo/bar`.

So, is it possible to only eliminate trailing slashes if it's actually *just one* trailing slash?

Sorry if this is a somewhat annoying or weird question!

Thanks.

Comment: Same question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19990838/remove-trailing-slash-from-sub-directory-folder-apache-1-3-42-directoryslash-off

Answer (score 26):

the following rule will match any URL ending in a slash and remove all slashes from the end of it:

```
RewriteRule ^(.*)/+$ $1 [R=301,L]
```

*Note:* The currently accepted answer only works for http not https but this one works for both.

Comment: @steve The completed answer is obviously going to be worth the wait.

Comment: I've refreshed this page for over 2 years now waiting for the answer ... This is the literally the last thing I need to do before putting my website live ...

Comment: Just noticed this today after so long. Maybe I should not have clarified to humour the other readers :)

Comment: The regex should match at least one character before `/`, so `\(.+)/+$`, otherwise you get an infinite redirect loop when requesting `/`.

Comment: @ironchicken Not if the rule is used in `.htaccess` (as stated in the question). However, by itself, the rule above would result in a malformed redirect if used in `.htaccess`!

Comment: "remove all slashes from the end" - the rule in the question already does that, which is what they are trying to avoid.

Answer (score 14):

change the rewrite rule to:

```
RewriteRule ^(.+[^/])/$ http://%{HTTP_HOST}/$1 [R=301,L]
```

in English: match the start of the string, one or more anything, NOT a slash, a slash, the end.

Comment: It seems that the `http://%{HTTP_HOST}/$1` should be `http://%{HTTP_HOST}$1` otherwise an extra / is added to the beginning of new url.

Comment: @AmirAliAkbari Not if the rule is being used in `.htaccess` (as stated in the question). You would only remove the slash in the _substitution_ string if the rule is being used in a _server_ or _virtualhost_ context. However, if that is the case then it would arguably be preferable to modify the `RewriteRule` _pattern_ instead and keep the slash in the target URL. eg. Change `^(.+[^/])/$` to `^/?(.+[^/])/$` - and this would now work in _all_ contexts.

Answer (score 5):

Here is a mod-alias based solution to remove trailing slash from urls :

```
RedirectMatch ^/(.*?)/$ /$1
```

You can use the above Redirect in your htaccess or server.config file.

This will redirect **/uri/** to */uri** .

Comment: This worked for me, aleemb's answer didn't work as I'm using virtual hosts.

Answer (score 4):

```
^(.+[^/])/$
```

I.e. the forelast character must not be a slash.

Answer (score 0):

If you only want to remove the trailing slashes from GET requests, use the below:

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_METHOD} =GET
RewriteRule ^(.*)/$ /$1 [L,R=301]
```