# mod_rewrite: remove trailing slash (only one!)

Tags: apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, redirect, url-rewriting

I use mod_rewrite/.htaccess for pretty URLs.

I'm using this condition/rule to eliminate trailing slashes (or rather: rewrite to the non-trailing-slash-URL, by a 301 redirect; I'm doing this to avoid duplicate content and because I like URLs with no trailing slashes better):

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^\.localhost$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.+)/$ http://%{HTTP_HOST}/$1 [R=301,L]
```

Working well so far. Only drawback:
it also forwards *"multiple-trailing-slash"-URLs* to *non-trailing-slash-URLs*.

Example:
`http://example.tld/foo/bar//////` forwards to `http://example.tld/foo/bar`
while I only want `http://example.tld/foo/bar/` to forward to `http://example.tld/foo/bar`.

So, is it possible to only eliminate trailing slashes if it's actually *just one* trailing slash?

Sorry if this is a somewhat annoying or weird question!

Thanks.

Comment: why asking the same question again? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3068091/mod-rewrite-remove-trailing-slash-only-one

Answer (score 0):

Try this pattern please

^(.+[^/])/$    instead of  ^(.+)/$

Comment: I suppose it's because of looping. Try to set the maxredirect option. For the details follow the link. http://articles.sitepoint.com/print/mod_rewrite-no-endless-loops