# Redirect xyz.html/ to xyz.html on large scale

Tags: html, .htaccess, seo, permalinks

I have a simple html website with over 50 html pages. From statistics-script I sometime see users on a page like xyz.html/ (which redirect to 404) instead of xyz.html. I know a simple way is to put a 301 redirect but there are too many pages. Can anyone suggest a way to redirect all incoming traffic to the links with forward slash '/' to the pages without forward slash? (traffic usually comes from social media)

```
like 

abc.html/ to abc.html
xyz.html/ to xyz.html
.
.
.
so on
```

**edit:**

I only want to do this on a specific directory not the whole domain. For example only to www.example.com/section/

```
   www.example.com/section/abc.html/ to www.example.com/section/abc.html
   www.example.com/section/xyz.html/ to www.example.com/section/xyz.html
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
 RewriteRule ^((.+)\.html)/$ http://<your-domain>/$1 [L,R=301]
```

Replace <your-domain> with the name of your domain (and folder if required).
Response is based on the data given here [mod_rewrite: remove trailing slash (only one!)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3068091/mod-rewrite-remove-trailing-slash-only-one)

Comment: use `^(section/(.+)\.html)/$` to only apply the rule to anyting in the `section` folder

Answer (score 0):

Depends on your server. For nginx, you need something along the lines of (didn't check though):

```
location ~\.html/$ {
    rewrite (.*)/$ $1 last;
}
```