# Remove Trailing Slash from Sub-directory Folder Apache 1.3.42 DirectorySlash Off .htaccess

Tags: apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I’m trying to remove the trailing slash from my sub-directory folders in Apache 1.3.42 however the command `DirectorySlash Off` is not supported in my version of Apache when I try to add the rule to my `.htaccess` file.

Currently my links behave like so:

- `www.example.com/folder` directs to `www.example.com/folder/`

What I want is:

- `www.example.com/folder/` to direct to `www.example.com/folder`

My current `.htaccess` file looks as follows:

```
AddType application/x-httpd-php .html

RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /

#non www to www

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^www\.
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://www.%{HTTP_HOST}/$1 [R=301,L]

#removing trailing slash

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*)/$ $1 [R=301,L]

#html

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^([^\.]+)$ $1.html [NC,L]

#index redirect

#directory remove index.html

RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} ^[A-Z]{3,9}\ /index\.html\ HTTP/ 
RewriteRule ^index\.html$ http://www.example.com/ [R=301,L]

#directory remove index 

RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} ^[A-Z]{3,9}\ /index\ HTTP/ 
RewriteRule ^index http://www.example.com/ [R=301,L]

#sub-directory remove index.html

RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} /index\.html
RewriteRule ^(.*)/index\.html$ /$1 [R=301,L]

#sub-directory remove index

RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} /index
RewriteRule ^(.*)/index /$1 [R=301,L]

#remove .html

RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} \.html
RewriteRule ^(.*)\.html$ /$1 [R=301,L]
```

I do realize this is more likely than not too difficult of a question to solve however I do appreciate you looking at it nevertheless.

Answer (score 3):

You need to add a couple of other rules besides removing the trailing slash. With `DirectorySlash Off`, the redirect from no slash to trailing slash stops, but if you access any directory, it will *print the contents of the directory* instead of displaying the index file.

This means you must internally add a trailing slash to directories. So change these lines:

```
#removing trailing slash

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*)/$ $1 [R=301,L]
```

To:

```
DirectorySlash Off

#removing trailing slash    
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST_FILENAME} \ /(.*)/(\ |$|\?)
RewriteRule ^(.*)/$ $1 [R=301,L]

# internally add the slash back
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !/$
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /$1/ [L]
```

Comment: Hello Jon,

Unfortunately as I have stated above DirectorySlash Off will not work with Apache 1.3.42 so that means I’m looking for a more advanced solution because your code simply gave me a 500 Internal Server Error.

Thanks anyways Jon.