# mod_rewrite rule for removing slashes and .html together

Tags: apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I have tried a number of combinations but just can't get the following scenario set up using mod_rewrite in Apache:

domain.com/folder/ - Remove the trailing "/" - Result = domain.com/folder

domain.com/folder/filename.html - Remove the .html and do not add a trailing "/"- Result = domain.com/folder/filename (this is for any filename that is not index)

domain.com/folder/index.html - Remove the filename, extension and trailing "/" - Result = domain.com/folder

[edit] - What I have currently, which removes .html but adds slash. But now I need to remove all slashes from urls (both folders and files):

```
  Options +FollowSymLinks
  RewriteEngine On
  RewriteBase /
# Add trailing slash to url
  RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
  RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !(\.[a-zA-Z0-9]{1,5}|/|#(.*))$
  RewriteRule ^(.*)$ $1/ [R=301,L]
# Remove .html extension from url
  RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
  RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME}\.html -f
  RewriteRule ^([^\.]+)/$ $1.html

  RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} ^[A-Z]{3,9}\ /.*\.html\ HTTP/
  RewriteRule ^(.*)\.html$ /$1 [R=301,L]
```

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: What do you currently have for your code?

Comment: Right now I have the following which removes the .html and adds a slash, but I now need to remove the slash from all URLs (both folders and .html files without the extension showing):

# Add trailing slash
  RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
  RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !(\.[a-zA-Z0-9]{1,5}|/|#(.*))$
  RewriteRule ^(.*)$ $1/ [R=301,L]
# Remove .html extension from url
  RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
  RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME}\.html -f
  RewriteRule ^([^\.]+)/$ $1.html

  RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} ^[A-Z]{3,9}\ /.*\.html\ HTTP/
  RewriteRule ^(.*)\.html$ /$1 [R=301,L]

Comment: Add that to the question, it's not ledgible in comments.

Comment: It's been a long day to say the least ;) #embarrassed. Edited.

Comment: you want to remove the slash but you have a rule adding a slash. why?

Comment: That was the first option. Then the slashes needed to be removed. No matter what I try I cannot get it to work. I removed the "Add trailing slash part", added a "no trailing slash" line at the end, etc... and it either did nothing, or created the infinite loop scenario. So I'm looking for a fresh pair of eyes or new code to achieve the goal.

Comment: Is `/folder` a real directory?

Comment: Yes, these are real folders and files, not WordPress style index.php manipulation.

Comment: This post is close: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21481137/htaccess-remove-php-html-and-trailing-slash  but it keeps the trailing slash for folders like folder/index.html  Trying to remove trailing slash from all URLs is what I'm stuck on.

Comment: Trailing slash should not be removed from a directory for security reasons.

Comment: What about combining "DirectorySlash Off" as described in http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19990838/remove-trailing-slash-from-sub-directory-folder-apache-1-3-42-directoryslash-off  You're saying there is no way to remove the .html extension for files that exist and have a display URL without a trailing slash for folders?

Comment: Yes it can be done with `DirectorySlash Off` but it is still a security issue for directories since you may accidentally show directory listing when `index.html` is not there.