# Adding special character in the end of the URL destroys webpage

Tags: javascript, php, css, html, web

Why is the webpage destroyed when I add a special character to the URL, especially the `/`?

For example,

> myproject.loc/page1.php/

How can I solve this?

Comment: why do you want to show it like that "?

Comment: Do you get a 404 error?

Comment: Does it really destroy your webpage?

Comment: @ferozakbar I dont what to show it like that. But when we had our thesis defense, the panelist try that then it ruin the webpage. So they told us to fix it. How can i fix it?

Comment: @NishantShrivastava Nope.

Comment: @HorseSMith Yes. It removes all the styles.

Comment: Have you really got a directory named "page1.php"? When you say it ruins the styling, I'm betting the styling link is like the name of the styling file, and you're not in the same directory anymore. Add a / at the beginning of the styling link to fix that issue.

Comment: I mean it removes the CSS. @HorseSMith

Comment: If the styling file with the CSS is at the root of the web directory, then you should be able to always reference it from whatever directory you're in by adding / in front of the name of the styling file. Like this: `/style.css` This works because "`/`" references the root, so then you get an always working absolute path to the styling file, instead of a relative path like just the filename of the styling file (which means it must find the styling file in the same directory as you're currently in, AKA page1.php, which I doubt is really a directory on your server, but rather a file).

Comment: @user3203544 I don't really like to ask, but it's normal to give an upvote to comments and answers etc you find useful.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to encode your URL while you are creating it. If the URL is gonna be created by javascript encode it by following command:

```
encodeURIComponent('myproject.loc/page1.php/"?');
```

or if you are creating URL in PHP use this:

```
urlencode('myproject.loc/page1.php/"?');
```

However it's not recommanded to use some special characters in a website URLs which want to follow SEO

Answer (score 1):

When you put a trailing slash after `page1.php` your browser interprets it as a directory and it ruins all of your relative paths.

If you really want the trailing slash after a filename you would need to use `apache url` rewrites.

Comment: How can I do that?Please help me.

Comment: Take a look at this thread http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3068091/mod-rewrite-remove-trailing-slash-only-one

Comment: Or you could make sure that all of your links and references are absolute instead of relative