# How to automatically remove trailing slash in .htaccess file

Tags: .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I would like to remove trailing slash automatically. When i insert slash at the end of the URL the page leads to Google search.Here my .htaccess file

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond $1 !^(index\.php|resources|robots\.txt)
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !(.*)/$
RewriteRule ^(.*) index.php/$1 [L,QSA]
```

Comment: This is so easy to Google....

Comment: Possible duplicate of [mod\_rewrite: remove trailing slash (only one!)](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3068091/mod-rewrite-remove-trailing-slash-only-one)

Answer (score 1):

Kindly try the code below. Insert it below `RewriteEngine On`.

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*)/$ /$1 [L,R=301]`
```