# 301 redirect from ending slash to without ending slash

Tags: .htaccess, redirect

How to make 301 redirect, from for example:
https://example.com/folder/subfolder/

to

https://example.com/folder/subfolder

Comment: Possible duplicate of [mod\_rewrite: remove trailing slash (only one!)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3068091/mod-rewrite-remove-trailing-slash-only-one)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To remove a trailing slash using `.htaccess` you can use:

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} (.+)/$
RewriteRule ^ %1 [R=301,L]
```

Make sure you clear your cache before you test this.