# How to delete backslashes in the End of the URLs directory with or without redirects on Wamp Server

Tags: php, .htaccess, directory, wampserver, backslash

please help me delete the end backslash from url,especially directories,like this:
from
localhost/mysite/user/
to
localhost/mysite/user

i have tried some php codes and htaccess commands but they loop the webpage instead deleting the backslash!!
i am using localhost wampserver offline for creating my website..
Please Help Me, what  i should do, Much Thanks.....

i have tried php codes and htaccess commands  found on the internet but they loop the redirect, and also used some htaccess that say you are forbidden accessing

```
//php example 1
<?php
$path = $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'];
if(substr($path, -1) == '/')
{
$path=rtrim( $path, '/\\' );
header("Location: $path");
}

?>

//php example 2
<?php
if( ($_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'] != "/") and 
preg_match('{/$}',$_SERVER['REQUEST_URI']) ) {
header ('Location: '.preg_replace('{/$}', '', $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI']));
exit();
}
?>
```

the Result if if i put  some commands for htaccess it 'll make the wamp server not working properly, or othe commands 'll make the server to say forbiddin accessing , or some other commands redirect my website,
also the php code redirect the website ...

Answer (score 0):

You could create a rewrite rule in the .htaccess

the following rule will match any URL ending in a slash and remove all slashes from the end of it:

```
RewriteRule ^(.*)/+$ $1 [R=301,L]
```

[mod_rewrite: remove trailing slash (only one!)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3068091/mod-rewrite-remove-trailing-slash-only-one)

Comment: i used this command :   RewriteEngine On

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*)\/(\?.*)?$ $1$2 [R=301,L]

Comment: but stops wamp server from working when i restart it

Comment: Well, it worked for many people, no idea why your apache is crashing