# How to remove double slash after domain by htaccess?

Tags: php, .htaccess

This is my .htaccess.

```
DirectorySlash Off

RewriteEngine On

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME}.php -f
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ $1.php

RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} ^[A-Z]{3,9}\ /.*\.php\ HTTP/
RewriteRule ^(.*)\.php$ /$1 [R=301,L]

# Ensure www. and https
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^www\. [OR]
RewriteCond %{HTTP:X-Forwarded-Proto} !https [OR]
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} off
RewriteRule ^ https://www.%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [L,R=301]

# Rewrite the URL to append a trailing slash to directories (internally)
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -d
RewriteRule (.*[^/])$ $1/ [L]
```

While this seems to be working properly while surfing on the web browser,the problem appears when our SEO Team Crawls using third party tools like Screaming Frog.
Urls appear as following:

```
*.mywebsite.com
*.mywebsite.com/blogs
*.mywebsite.com/blogs/blog-1
*.mywebsite.com/about-us
....
*.mywebsite.com//
*.mywebsite.com//blogs
*.mywebsite.com//blogs/blog-1
*.mywebsite.com//about-us
....
```

I do not want the urls with two slash after domain. I tried many solutions available on internet but none of them worked.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [mod\_rewrite: remove trailing slash (only one!)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3068091/mod-rewrite-remove-trailing-slash-only-one)

Comment: What does this have to do with URL rewriting in the first place? _"when our SEO Team Crawls using third party tools like Screaming Frog. Urls appear as following:"_ - then most likely either these tools get something wrong, or your HTML output contains wrong references to begin with.

Comment: When you enter `mywebsite.com/about-us` in browser does it redirect to `mywebsite.com//about-us` ?

Comment: @anubhava No, id does not redirect.

Comment: @SimoneRossaini Thank You for the reply, but I have already tried those answers and none of them worked for me.

Comment: Ok then clarify when do you get double slash in URLs?

Comment: @anubhava When our SEO Team crawls our website in tools like screaming frog, it shows that the url with double slash exists. 
I tried redirecting double slash urls to urls with no slash (using many solutions available on stackoverflow and other blogs) but none of the redirection works. The double slash stays as it is without being removed.

Comment: Crawler tool only scans your HTML pages and if that is finding URLs with `//` then it must be coming from your pages. I can suggest you a rule that will redirect `//`to single `/` but your HTML source won't chane.

Comment: @anubhava Sure, you can provide me the new redirect rule, I will try to use it.

Answer (score 1):

You can use this redirect rule to remove `//` from anywhere in URLs:

```bash
RewriteEngine On

# remove multiple slashes from URL (Better)
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} \s[^?]*//
RewriteRule .* /$0 [R=302,L,NE]
```

Regex pattern `\s[^?]*//` matches `//` anywhere before matching a `?` (stat of the query string) in `THE_REQUEST` variable which represents original Apache request.

Please note that pattern in `RewriteRule` by default strips out multiple `/`s by Apache `mod_rewrite` engine.